# Why Nifi not showing the processor description?

Tags: apache-nifi

Apache Nifi showing blank processor description. Please find the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi4zu.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `zoomed out` too far.

To see descriptions **Zoom-In**  by clicking on the below button in **Navigate panel** until you see the descriptions on the **`canvas`**.

[image]

**(or)**

Use mouse scroller to Zoom-In.